# About using JSON with PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, foreach, getjson

I have a problem that I can not solve. JQuery works with getJSON, php does not work with foreach. The error I get in PHP:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\plreserv\index.php on line 14
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\plreserv\index.php on line 14

JSON output from the service:

```
{
    dataList: [
        {
            Date:'11.08.2017',
            Com:'Spr',
            BlsId:'5',
            Type:'break',
            TypeCheck:'0,5',
            perma:'Normal',
            CommaDetail:'0,,,particle,0,,,7',
            Pom:[
                {
                    Num:'1',
                    status:'1',
                    val:'37349',
                    lang:'tr'
                },
                {
                    Num:'2',
                    status:'1',
                    val:'37350',
                    lang:'ru'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

My php code:

```
$file = file_get_contents(url);
$json = json_decode($file);
foreach($json as $data):
// code
endforeach;
```

There are 18 pages like this and none of them work in PHP. This is the error I get from the JSON viewer:

[Image attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ile2M.png)

I'm sorry for my bad english. Thanks.

Comment: What is shown is not valid JSON. Validate it on jsonlint.com. Beyond that you need to show the code that is not working also

Comment: And the PHP you use is?

Comment: ^ this, and can you show us your php code with the foreach in it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: $file = file_get_json("http://localhost:4000/otelservice/");
$json = json_decode($file);
foreach($json as $data):

endforeach;

my php code.

Comment: Don't add the code as a comment, update your question instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Returning JSON from a PHP Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064444/returning-json-from-a-php-script)

Answer (score 0):

This is the right format of your json:

```
[
{
    "Date":"11.08.2017",
    "Com":"Spr",
    "BlsId":"5",
    "Type":"break",
    "TypeCheck":"0,5",
    "perma":"Normal",
    "CommaDetail":"0,,,particle,0,,,7",
    "Pom":[
        {
            "Num":"1",
            "status":"1",
            "val":"37349",
            "lang":"tr"
        },
        {
            "Num":"2",
            "status":"1",
            "val":"37350",
            "lang":"ru"
        }
    ]
}]
```

all inside json must be wrapped by double quote (except integer, you haven't)

Comment: Thank you so much. But I did not make this source. I bought it and that's the source :(

Comment: may i know what the `file_get_contents` return?

Comment: When I use file_get_content, the return value is the value I sent above